# How to connect the ear to the rest of the head cleanly?

Tags: modeling

I've done some googling and I think I've seen some stuff about using the boolean modifier? However there is space between the edges so I'm unsure how well it would work. There are also faces that overlap and intersect each other.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Comment: is this a sculpt?

Comment: I think we would really need to see the topology (wireframe) of your head and ear to get a better idea.